# How to split dataset into train validate test sets correctly, in simple clear way?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, dataset, train-test-split

I have a dataset with `100` samples, I want to split it into `75%`, `25%`, `25%` for both Train Validate, and Test respectively, then I want to do that again with different ratios such as `80%`, `10%`, `10%`.

For this purpose, I was using the `code` down, but I think that it's not splitting the data correctly on the second step, because it will split the data from `85%` to `(85% x 85%)`, and `(15% x 15%)`.

#### My question is that:

Is there a nice clear way to do the splitting in the correct way for any given ratios?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split Train Test Validate
X_, X_val, Y_, Y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_, Y_, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always do it manually. A bit messy but you can create a function

```
def my_train_test_split(X, y, ratio_train, ratio_val, seed=42):
    idx = np.arange(X.shape[0])
    np.random.seed(seed)
    np.random.shuffle(idx)

    limit_train = int(ratio_train * X.shape[0])
    limit_val = int((ratio_train + ratio_val) * X.shape[0])

    idx_train = idx[:limit_train]
    idx_val = idx[limit_train:limit_val]
    idx_test = idx[limit_val:]

    X_train, y_train = X[idx_train], y[idx_train]
    X_val, y_val = X[idx_val], y[idx_val]
    X_test, y_test = X[idx_test], y[idx_test]

    return X_train, X_val, X_test, y_train, y_val, y_test
```

Ratio test is assumed to be 1-(ratio_train+ratio_val).

Comment: I can just change my code:  `test_size=0.15` to `ratio = 0.15`, `test_size=ratio/(1-ratio)` but I thought if there is a more elegant way to do it.